# Show that there is a vector $w$ in ${\rm ker}\ (T)$ such that $v=u+w$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces such that $T:U\rightarrow V$ is a linear map. Suppose also that $u$ and $v$ are vectors in $V$ such that $f(u)=f(v)$. Show that there is a vector $w \in \rm ker(T)$ such that $v=u+w$.

If $f(u)=f(v)$, then $u=v$. Then surely $w=0$ since ${\rm ker}(T)$ is a subspace of $V$ and every subspace contains the zero vector? I am not quite sure how to write this as a formal proof?

Comment: HINT: $f(v-u)=0$ and $v=u+(v-u)$.

Comment: Note that for an arbitrary linear map, $T(u) = T(v)$ does *not* imply $u = v$. It implies that $0 = T(u) - T(v) = T(u - v)$ and hence ...

Comment: $f$ is the same as $T$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that $f$ is the same as $T$